# Ive been stuck trying to figure out how to code the final total value

Tags: python-3.x

> This program will ask the user for the number of half-dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies s/he has and then
> compute the total value.  The total value of the change should be shown both as the total number of cents, and then as
> the separate  number of dollars (i.e., a whole number) and cents remaining (also as a whole number). I need help trying to get the "final total value" of this loop, ive been stuck on this for some time now.

```
def getCoin(coinType) :
    coinval = -1
    while coinval < 0:
        try:
           coinval = int(input(coinType))
           if coinval < 0:
               print( "Coin counts cannot be negative. Please re-enter.")
        except ValueError:
           print("Illegal input. Value converted to zero")
           coinval = -1
    #challenge for class on 8/30: keep asking user for value until good one is given: >=0  
    return coinval

print("welcome to the change calculator")
print()

choice= input("do you have change? (Y/N)")
while choice.upper() =="Y":
    print("Your choice was:" + choice)

    hd = getCoin(" # Half-Dollars?")
    q = getCoin(" # Quarters?")
    d = getCoin(" # Dimes?")
    n = getCoin(" # Nickels?")
    p = getCoin(" # Pennies?")
    
    totalvalue = (hd * 50) + (q * 25) + (d * 10) + (n * 5) + p
    dollars = totalvalue //100 #integer division
    cents = totalvalue % 100    #modulus gives just the remainder
    print("you have " + str(totalvalue) + "cents.")

        print(" this is " + str(dollars) + "dollars and " + str(cents) + "cents")
        choice = input("do you have more change? (Y/N): ")
    
    
        
    print("Thanks for using the change calculator")
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'final total value'

Comment: Basically the sum of all the money if the user decide  to say they dont have any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate variable outside the loop to keep track of the sum of all the money every time the user decides to press "Y":

```py
final_total_value = 0

choice= input("do you have change? (Y/N)")
while choice.upper() =="Y":
    ...
    totalvalue = (hd * 50) + (q * 25) + (d * 10) + (n * 5) + p
    ...
    final_total_value += totalvalue
    ...
    choice = input("do you have more change? (Y/N): ")

print("Final total value " + str(final_total_value) + "cents.")
```